# Java Array Standard Deviation and Median

Tags: java

Need to add Median and Standard Deviation to the following program, but I have no idea where to start, I know what I want it to do but am not sure how to make it happen especially since the median has to come after the sorted numbers but if I put it in as void Median (), I loose the sorted array. Please help! Any assistance is much appreciated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JScannerO
{
    public JScannerO(){}
    public JScannerO(int A)
    {
        HowMuch = A;
    }
    void GenerateNumbers()
    {
        int k,Hide;
        k = 0;
        while ( k < HowMuch )
        {
            Hide = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            if ( Hide > 9 && Hide < 100 )
            {
                Hanson[k] = Hide;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    void DisplayNumbers()
    {
        int k;
        for ( k = 0; k < HowMuch; k++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\tThe numbers are : " + Hanson[k]);
        }
    }
    void BiggestNumber()
    {
        int k,Biggest;
        Biggest = Hanson[0];
        for ( k = 0; k < HowMuch; k++)
        {
            if ( Biggest < Hanson[k] ) Biggest = Hanson[k];
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\tThe biggest number is : " + Biggest);
    }
    void SmallestNumber()
    {
        int k,Smallest;
        Smallest = Hanson[0];
        for ( k = 0; k < HowMuch; k++)
        {
            if ( Smallest > Hanson[k] ) Smallest = Hanson[k];
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\tThe Smallest number is : " + Smallest);
    }
    void Average()
    {
        int k,Sum;
        double Average;
        Sum = 0;
        for ( k = 0; k < HowMuch; k++)
        {
            Sum = Sum + Hanson[k];
        }
        Average = 1.0 * Sum / HowMuch;
        System.out.format("\n\n\t\tThe Average number is : %7.2f",Average);
    }
    void Sort()
    {
        int k,Hide;
        boolean DidISwap;
        DidISwap = true;
        while (DidISwap)
        {
            DidISwap = false;
            for ( k = 0; k < HowMuch - 1; k++)
            {
                if ( Hanson[k] > Hanson[k+1] )
                {
                    Hide = Hanson[k ];
                    Hanson[k] = Hanson[k+1];
                    Hanson[k+1] = Hide ;
                    DidISwap = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\t\tThe Sorted Numbers : \n");
    }
    private int HowMuch;
    private int[] Hanson = new int[100];
}
```

**This is run by using a calling program**

Comment: Please edit your question and pay attention the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: What do you mean, you lose the array? If your array is sorted, your median is just array[array.length/2], if length is odd, and the average of array[array.length/2] and array[array.length/2+1] otherwise

Comment: Do I nest that under void Sort() to keep the sorted array? I was under the impression that if I use void Median () then I have to sort the numbers again?

Comment: If your array Hansen is a class variable, then simply accessing the array indices will not "unsort" the array, if that's what you mean. Just make sure you don't call median on an unsorted array. However, un-indented code is hard to read. If you want a clearer answer please format your question

Comment: Please, please, please, do not use names with initial caps for variable names (or method names).  Use those only for class names.  This makes your code much easier for experienced programmers to read.

Comment: I think someone just formatted it - Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Hot Licks, I didn't realize that.

Comment: For median you need to write a sort routine that RETURNS a sorted array, rather than just printing it out.  You can share the routine between your "median" and "sort" functions, so it only needs to be written once (and maybe only executed once).

Comment: (But note that your sort routine modifies "Hanson", leaving it sorted.)

Comment: Set a boolean attribute (say, "sorted") keeping track of your array is sorted or not.  Then inside those methods that require a sorted array (Median, etc) have them called Sort() if "sorted" is false.

Comment: It's an array which is statically declared to be of size 100. There is no need to bother checking, any computer on Earth can afford paying O(N) in this case, it makes no noticeable difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

You have a sorting algorithm there that does the work for you!

Can't you just write a

```
public int median() { 
  Sort();
  return Hanson[Math.floor(Hanson/2)]; 
}
```

?

This will cost you O(N) instead of O(1), but it is not error-prone and does what you need to do - especially since your "Hanson" array has only size 100 so we can just not care at this point.

As a final remark: function names are ALWAYS in lower camelCase, i.e. it's sort() and not Sort(), and it's calculateSomething() and not Calculate_Something() or any other variant.

There are kind of no exceptions to this rule, and that will make your code (much) more readable. Consider installing CheckStyle in Eclipse (http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) in order to have an interactive guide to style when you are writing :-)